# Build a reactive iterative form on onchange function in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have select box, depends on the selected option I need to show array items

statically I have one array , depends on the selection I am building reactive form arry ccording to my requirement

static array like

```
  form_objects = [  

 {  
     "id":1,
     "legend":"businessModule",
     "group":[  

          {  
              "id":1,
              "permission":{  
                 "controleType":"ff",
                 "id":2,
                 "key":"create Business",
                  "legend":"businessModule",
                  "label": "create Business"
              },
              "roles":[  
                 {  
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"self"
                 },
                 {  
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"other"
                 }
              ]
           },


          {  
              "id":1,
              "permission":{  
                 "controleType":"ff",
                 "id":2,
                  "legend":"businessModule",
                 "key":"edit business",
                 "label": "edit business"
              },
              "roles":[  
                 {  
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"self"
                 },
                 {  
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"other"
                 }
              ]
           }

     ]
  },


 {  
     "id":2,
     "legend":"PanicModule",
     "group":[  

          {  
              "id":1,
              "permission":{  
                 "controleType":"ff",
                 "id":2,
                  "legend":"PanicModule",
                 "key":"create panic",
                  "label": "create panic"
              },
              "roles":[  
                 {  
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"self"
                 },
                 {  
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"other"
                 }
              ]
           },


          {  
              "id":1,
              "permission":{  
                 "controleType":"ff",
                 "id":2,
                  "legend":"PanicModule",
                 "key":"edit panic",
                  "label": "edit panic"
              },
              "roles":[  
                 {  
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"self"
                 },
                 {  
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"other"
                 }
              ]
           }

     ]
  }
```

]

I want to build reacive array like this

```
 {  
   "roleName":"",
   "roleDescription":"",
   "permissionModules":"PanicModule",
   "permission":[  
      {  
         "id":2,
         "key":"create Business",
         "legend":"businessModule",
         "ischecked":null,
         "label":"create Business",
         "roles":[  
            {  
               "id":1,
               "name":"self"
            },
            {  
               "id":2,
               "name":"other"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "key":"edit business",
         "legend":"businessModule",
         "ischecked":null,
         "label":"edit business",
         "roles":[  
            {  
               "id":1,
               "name":"self"
            },
            {  
               "id":2,
               "name":"other"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My requirement is when I select **Business Module** I need to show business permission and roles, If I select Pnic Modle I need show panic role and
 permissions,

I want to build it using reactive form , So I tried like this 
https://plnkr.co/edit/OZGEWDEa0UzMXFO6lreG?p=preview

I don't know is this good approach or not, Pleace help me,
Thanks in advance